# Duvida de implantação arquitetura com elasticsearch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

Ola,

é normal usar o elasticsearch como backend direto em uma aplicação para web.

Referente a segurança?

FrontEnd (js) -> Backend (elasticsearch)

ou

FrontEnd (js) -> seu backend -> service (elasticsearch)

A minha grande preocupação seria na segurança de acesso ao elasticsearch.

Alguem já usa elasticsearch em produção desta forma...

Grato

Comment: Não é normal usar o ES como "back-end" até por que ele é um indexador de documentos e não um banco de dados.

Answer (score 1):

Depende muito...

Eu não recomendaria utilizar o Elasticsearch como banco de dados primário, até por que ele é um documento. Uma vez que os dados estão lá, os dados são transformados e armazenados no cluster do elasticsearch para análise. Mas se você está construindo sistemas completamente novos, então você tem TOTAL liberdade.

Eu ficaria com a segunda opção: Front-end -> Back-end -> DB -> ES

O ideal é você possuir o seu modelo de negócio funcionando normalmente em um banco de dados SQL ou noSQL (você escolhe) e caso você precise analisar ou consultar dados utilizar o Elasticsearch para usufruir de sua facilidade e alto desempenho.

Comment: Show, Obrigado, eu já tenho uma arquitetura funcional e meu db principal é outro, seria apenas essa arquitetura para consulta msm, mais a minha preocupação é a segurança de usar apenas elastic, sobre acesso externo ao elastic.... Muito obrigado pela resposta :)

Comment: Bacana @SidicleiF.Almeida ! Fico feliz em poder ajuda-lo.

Answer (score 1):

ElasticSearch é um motor de busca real time baseado em lucene, naturalmente distribuído, escalável e servidor rest. Ele basicamente usa o lucene para fazer indexação dos dados e torna isso escalável através de clusterização e replicação dos índices.

ElasticSearch deve ser usado apenas para busca pois não possui forte integridade referencial e em algum momento os índices podem ser corrompidos, principal quando você começa a escalar os nós.

O ideal é você usar a seguinte estrutura: Front End JS/ Back End JS/ Acesso a dados(Algum banco relacional ou NOSQL e indexar o que é relevante para pesquisa no elasticsearch.

O uso do elasticsearch é simples a primeira vista, mas manter a estabilidade do cluster se torna cada vez mais difícil a medida que o fluxo de dados aumenta e você precisa de mais escala.